# Are there scientific studies related to the Bitcoin technology?

Tags: academic-research

Besides “[Bitcoin: A Peer-to-Peer Electronic Cash System](http://www.bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf)”, which is more like a brief description of the general framework, are there other ‘scientific or research grade’ studies about Bitcoin technology? Can similar *decentralized* crypto-currency models be found in the literature?

Comment: related question: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/36/46

Comment: also, note that the paper you link has not been published or peer-reviewed and thus it is contentious if it counts as a scientific study.

Comment: @Artem: Yes, that's a good guide to roughly understand the mechanisms of Bitcoin. But nothing really convincing in there.

Comment: Voting to close because there can't be an accepted complete answer to this question.

Comment: @ripper: The problem is that some knowledge about existing works is needed if we are to allow science/technology-related questions here. My opinion is that these questions are obviously on-topic here, but maybe we should start some discussion on meta?

Comment: The source references section of the white paper contains several research publications and papers that point (some directly, some indirectly) to the *need for* and *inevitable emergence* of Bitcoin. Since Bitcoin emerged from cypherpunk efforts to reclaim privacy and autonomy from the state, it is less coordinated academic effort, and more innovation out of social need. Much like *guerilla warfare* was rapidly born out of modern circumstance (overwhelming adversary) rather than a systematic formulation during years of institutionalized research effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's group all the answers in this Wiki. Suggestions shall be provided in new answers, relevant (voted) ones will be included in this list, sorted by category and publication date.

#### Distributed currency models

- [2008] Chapter 2 of Flavio Garcia PhD thesis: “[Formal and Computational Cryptography: Protocols, Hashes and Commitments](http://dare.ubn.kun.nl/dspace/handle/2066/40158)”.

#### Bitcoin studies

- [2011, Jul] ArXiv paper by F. Reid, M. Harrigan: “[An Analysis of Anonymity in the Bitcoin System](http://arxiv.org/abs/1107.4524)”

Comment: I think Garcia's thesis was published in 2008; the author was born in 1978... which can be a bit misleading on the title page of the pdf.

Comment: Yes, this was looking rather strange :-) This is wiki, it means you are encouraged to fix mistakes by yourself. (Btw, that's also true for obvious mistakes in normal posts.)

Answer (score 9):

Bitcoin is a relatively new phenomenon and the peer-review process takes a while, so there is not much out there yet.

The most notable is a network analysis of bitcoin transactions done around the alleged "allinvain" theft earlier this year.

http://arxiv.org/abs/1107.4524

Other than that, there are currently a few articles published in academic journals that focus on bitcoin (as well as pop-sci and pop-compsci articles in various places)

For example

Grinberg, Reuben, Bitcoin: An Innovative Alternative Digital Currency (April 21, 2011). Available at SSRN: http://ssrn.com/abstract=1817857

The best answer may be to do this in the form of a community wiki where articles published in academic journals can be posted by subject, as if bitcoin survives it will obviously start to receive a lot of attention.

Comment: Thanks for the first link. The second one is not technology related.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there are studies about decentralized digital currencies. Some of them use ideas very similar to what Bitcoin chose, for instance refer to chapter 2 of [this thesis](http://dare.ubn.kun.nl/dspace/handle/2066/40158). The following Google scholar serarches will give you more reading:

http://scholar.google.ca/scholar?q=Decentralized+digital+currencies&hl=en&btnG=Search&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=on

and

http://scholar.google.ca/scholar?q=related:hCw5g5lkHWcJ:scholar.google.com/&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5

The basic premise of a decentralized mint is not a new idea, and has been studied for a while.

Answer (score 3):

I think that http://bitcoinacademic.wordpress.com could be able to help. There is a wide collection of academic research in many fields. However, you are right, there are not that many peer reviewed journal articles out there, but I do think some of this research is valuable and provides interesting insights.

Answer (score 2):

There are some papers on Bitcoin and related topics here:
 - http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Research

Answer (score 0):

Christian Decker maintains a pretty extended list of academic studies about Bitcoin : https://cdecker.github.io/btcresearch/.