# Estimated amount of Bitcoin users

Tags: user-base

I am writing a Business plan and attempting to make some financial projections based upon the population of bitcoin users, has anyone publicly produced any estimate as of 2014 of how many active users are within the bitcoin ecosystem? 
If not, has any project, research paper or organisation attempted a partial count or proposed a methodology for counting the amount of users in the ecosystem?

Comment: possible duplicateː [How can you tell how many users Bitcoin has?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/731/5406)

Answer (score 0):

To find out numer of transactions per day:
http://blockchain.info/charts/n-transactions

To find out unique addresses used each day:
http://blockchain.info/charts/n-unique-addresses

Now here is where the magic happens. You have to bring in your own calculation base for what the above means in terms of unique users.