# Any statistics on usage of Bitcoins by region or country?

Tags: adoption, user-base

I would like to know if there are any statistics on turnover of Bitcoins for each country in the world. A very rough way would be to get a statistic on which traffic to Bitcoin.org by country.

Comment: Are you interested in how much Bitcoins each country generates, or how interested people are in Bitcoins in those countries? For first one you would have to get statistics from a couple major pools, for the second - either bitcoin.org, or the forum. I can give you some rough data from my calculator website if you want on traffic sources.

Comment: @ThePiachu I am mostly interested the turnover of Bitcoins in each country (not the level of mining). But if that cannot be provided, then the second statistic.

Comment: Similar question that might be of interest: [Is there data on the geographic distribution of bitcoin users?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/696/is-there-data-on-the-geographic-distribution-of-bitcoin-users)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[WebGL Globe](http://blockchain.info/nodes-globe?series=48hrs) shows bitcoin nodes seen during last 48 hours. Install [Chrome Web browser](http://www.google.com/chrome) if you have problem rendering WebGL.

[Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends?q=bitcoin&ctab=0&geo=all&date=mtd&sort=0) has countries, cities and languages sorted by number of bitcoin related search queries.

Comment: First link doesn't seem to be working anymore

Answer (score 2):

Serith provides a link that shows location of Bitcoin nodes.  Beyond that Bitcoin specifically makes geolocation stats difficult.  Addresses are intentionally random and arbitrary.  You can look at transaction to determine senders IP address however that can be obfuscated and will not correctly reflect anyone using a web based wallets.

For bitcoin generation that is more difficult as roughly 80% of all Bitcoins are generated via a pool so any data in blockchain will simply indicate the location of the pool not the miners that make it up.

Answer (score 2):

You can see how many times bitcoin was downloaded by going to sourceforge and looking up bitcoin.

For example here is how many times bitcoin v4.0 was download by the United States:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/bitcoin/files/Bitcoin/bitcoin-0.4.0/stats/timeline

Comment: And here's the list/map by country: http://sourceforge.net/projects/bitcoin/files/Bitcoin/bitcoin-0.4.0/stats/map

Comment: sourceforge is very different from the past. beware of that site. lot of links are scams/viruses etc.

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a breakdown](http://99bitcoins.com/bitcoin-trends-throughout-world/) of Bitcoin by countries taken form Google Trends:

What you can see in that Estonia and Finland are first and only after that comes the US.

Comment: The linked site is offline :(. StackExchange recommends you paste some relevant parts of the linked document to avoid having to visit the site. In this case, some segments from the site could help finding any reposts of the same data. Now I instead continue searching.

Comment: The link was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how accurate it is, but here's a cool live map showing transactions - http://fiatleak.com. Portrays China having the bulk of the transactions, at least currently.

Answer (score -1):

For a very rough guide you could look at transaction volumes on the exchanges for different currencies..

e.g. [Exchange volume distribution](http://bitcoincharts.com/charts/volumepie/)

Comment: I think you should post this as a comment not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

If the question is turnover ie purchases /sales/volumes then its here  http://btckan.com/price

and its CHINA who is the leader by 2-1 and some days 4-1

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=319898.0