# Are there Bitcoin users in Asia especially Southeast Asia ? I'm from Malaysia

Tags: news-coverage

Are there many users of Bitcoins in Asian countries ?  I am from Malaysia.
If there are, I would like to give it a try too.

Comment: This is not a great question for StackExchange, it is for example hard to know what "many" means. If you want to know statistics of users per country there is a question regarding that [here](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1706/any-statistics-on-usage-of-bitcoins-by-region-or-country). If you want to connect with other users in your country, try to phrase the question that way, for example by asking for existing communities in that country.

Comment: Yea, I'm in Singapore.......

Answer (score 0):

At LocalBitcoins.com you find some Malaysian traders:

[Malyasian LocalBitcoins.com trades country listing](https://localbitcoins.com/country/MY)

Also, there is [Asian specific discussion forum](https://localbitcoins.com/forums/#!/regional/asia).